# server hard drive space monitoring

Tags: monitoring, hard-drive

looking for a freeware program to monitor my hard drive space.

Then send me an email when it goes below a certian % i have not been able to find any freeware on google so far so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic for ServerFault. Please check out our [FAQ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) and [`check_disk`](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_disk) plugin:

```
./check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/hdb1
```

`DISK OK - free space: /data 94452 MB (98% inode=99%);| /data=1219MB;80632;90711;0;100791`